i Want to add the the action bar using getSupportActionBar() but it throws an Null pointer exception
Theese are the code
package com.example.lee;
public class Activity_Cricket extends AppCompatActivity {

Button button;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    EdgeToEdge.enable(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cricket);



    button =findViewById(R.id.a_apply);
    String Activity = "Cricket";
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Activity_Cricket.this, Contact_form.class);
            intent.putExtra("activity_name", Activity);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}

}
It does not show error in gradle build but when i try to open the activity, the app keeps on stopping and the logcat shows this error
enter code here
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.lee, PID: 20944
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.lee/com.example.lee.Activity_Cricket}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:203)
at com.example.lee.Activity_Cricket.onCreate(Activity_Cricket.java:30)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776) 
2024

The Stacktrace is showing that the error is being caused on line 30 of the Activity_Cricket.java. Could you maybe provide the full code? Additionally you can inspect what's at line 30 in your program, it could be an issue with the manifest and you haven't registered the class in the manifest.

Have you put your activity in menifest file like this
<activity android:name="com.example.lee.Activity_Cricket" />

OR other option
check in your java file. have you put below line in onCreate() method
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main) //your layout file name


I guess you try to call .GetSupportActionBar() inside the Fragment. So the trouble is in the backwards compatibility. You'll need to cast it in the ActionBarActivity
((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle(R.string.subtitle);

The NullPointerException throws cause this command is in Activity API

I didn't use any fragments bro
